# Update table with same value based on given ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i would like to update a table with mySQL where rows got the same name as the name of given ID and increase and decrease their file_version.

The function should restore and older version of the file.

My table looks like this:

```
ID    |    name    |    file_version
1     |  book-1    |    1
2     |  book-1    |    2
3     |  book-1    |    3
4     |  book-2    |    1
```

The function gives the variables $docId and $fileVersion.

First i search for the max. file_version in the table and store it in a variable.

```
$query = 
'SELECT max(file_version) FROM myTable where doc_name in (
    SELECT doc_name FROM myTable
WHERE id = '.$docId.');';
$result1 = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result1);
$maxVersion = $row[0];
```

After that i set the file_version of the desired ID to max.

```
$query2 = 'SELECT file_version FROM dscQm_docs WHERE id='.$docId.';';
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result2);
$fileVersion = $row[0];
```

Now comes the tricky part. 
I would like to set the file_version of all docs with the same name as the name of the given ID -1 if their file_version is higher than the file_version of the given ID.

Here's my approach:

```
    $query4 = '
        UPDATE myTable SET file_version = file_version -1 WHERE( 
        SELECT * FROM myTable 
        WHERE name in (
           SELECT name FROM myTable
           WHERE id = '.$docId.' AND file_version > '.$fileVersion.'
        );
    ';
```

That doesn't work.

I'm sorry..i'm not good in SQL. I know this is crap.

Could you help me with the last SQL statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a legacy application? Otherwise there's no reason you should be using the terribly antiquated `mysql_query` interface.

Comment: Why don't you just set `file_version` to be `MAX(file_version)` in that other table for all entries with the same `name`? Your requirements here are hard to follow. Why `ID - 1`?

Comment: Despite of fact that you're not using `PDO` (because you should, really), you should try increasing counts using `SET field = field - 1`.

Comment: +1 for correctly assessing your own efforts to date. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query4 = '
        UPDATE myTable SET file_version = file_version -1 WHERE name like (
           SELECT name FROM myTable
           WHERE id = '.$docId.' AND file_version > '.$fileVersion.'
        )';
```

Try this?

EDIT: If u know the name, why don't you just compare the name only?

Like:

```
 $query4 = "UPDATE myTable SET file_version = file_version -1 WHERE name like '$name'";
```

EDIT2: Why don't you work OO? Instead of using so many different queries? To always get 1 value... Then you can store all the data related to 1 row at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you will avoid the much dreaded IN operator with subqueries (they can sometimes be inefficient, to say the least)!

```
update myTable as t1
left join myTable as t2 on (t1.name = t2. name)
set t2.file_version = t2.file_version -1
where t2.file_version > t1.file_version
and t1.id = *YOUR_ID*
```